# Bundling retina images only in iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios

Can we use retina images only for iOS apps? Do apps work on 3GS devices without the non-retina images.

Please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just try to run your Retina-only app on a non-Retina simulator?

Comment: actually, We have lots of images in single apps. More than 50MB. If i remove Non Ratina images then Size goes to down.

Answer (score 11):

The only non-retina images needed for an iOS app is the icon and the default image.

For all in-app images, it's fine to bundle retina versions only and let non-retina devices scale them down. I've done it myself on a few occasions to get below the cellular network download limit on App Store and I've never been rejected because of that.

Of course, not providing non-retina images may decrease performance and image quality on older devices due to the required down-scale operations, but that may be fine if you really need to decrease the app size.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, e.g. the Icon is required in Non-Retina and for the App Store are Retina-Screenshots required, too.

You can test if Retina-Images will automatically resized if there is no Non-Retina available but I can't say if your app will be rejected or not.

---

**Update:** As Retterdesdialogs mentioned, Retina-Images will be resized to Non-Retina, but it's not recommend and I highly recommend to not do this!

Comment: It will resize the images to non retina, but this is not recommended. Before i get flamed from users like in another post - try it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the larger images, but this could lead to a slower performance if the number of images on the screen is too big.

Comment: You'd also have to scale down the images, as CodaFi suggests, resulting in much worse performance, both CPU and memory

Comment: Yes, and this scaling will occur automatically if the frames of the images are fixed.

Comment: downloading larger images takes longer as well

Answer (score 2):

IPhone 4/4S uses 2x the image dimensions of an iPhone 3GS. If you supply only retina images then the image will be twice the size that it should be on the iPhone 3GS.

Answer (score 1):

You must keep separate images for both iphone 3 and iphone 4 and if the app is in the iphone 4 you can use the images with double the resolution of iphone 3 images.