# Can we use only retina image for retina and non retina device in my application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, retina-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bundling retina images only in iOS apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329718/bundling-retina-images-only-in-ios-apps)

I having lots of images in single project and thats why i only wants to display on retina images can we use retina for non retina device??